# Sorting array containing dictionaries and foreign letters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array which contains a bunch of dictionaries that consists of two keys called name and value.

I'm trying to sort the array based on the name key of the dictionary - But the dictionary contains Danish letters that show up in the wrong order (fx 'a å b c', instead of 'a b c .. å') - How do i get this to sort correctly with the danish characters?

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
self.cityOptionsArray = (NSMutableArray *)[tempCityArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSortDescriptor` has an initializer that allows you to invoke a custom compare-method on the objects it acts upon.

In your case, (and since your keys are `NSStrings`) you want to use  `localizedCompare:`.

You can use it like this:

```
NSSortdescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
          initWithKey:@"name"
          ascending:YES
          selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
```

Please remember to release it, after you're done with it.

For further reference, see *[Sort Descriptor Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/SortDescriptors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000174i)*.

Comment: Thanks :) And I have released it - It was just a small snippet from my file :)

Comment: This answer works for me also. I have an array of NSMutableDictionaries as my array and using initWithKey I am selecting which key should be the order referenced to. NOTICE that it works for ordering String type objects which contains letters, but it's not good for Strings which contains only numbers, such as NSNumber as NSString format.